# Create Payment Request API

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, payment-request-api

I am trying to integrate the Payment Request API for the Google Pay for Payments using javascript but my code returns a PaymentRequest is not defined error.

Here is my code.

```
CODE:

const supportedInstruments = [
  {
    supportedMethods: ['https://tez.google.com/pay'],
    data: {
      pa: 'abc@gmail.com',
      pn: 'abc',
      tr: '1234ABCD',  // your custom transaction reference ID
      url: 'http://url/of/the/order/in/your/website',
      mc: '1234', // your merchant category code
      tn: 'Purchase in Merchant',
    },
  }
];

const details = {
  total: {
    label: 'Total',
    amount: {
      currency: 'INR',
      value: '10.01', // sample amount
    },
  },
  displayItems: [{
    label: 'Original Amount',
    amount: {
      currency: 'INR',
      value: '10.01',
    },
  }],
};

let request = null;
try {
  request = new PaymentRequest(supportedInstruments, details);
} 
catch (e) {
  console.log('Payment Request Error: ' + e.message);
  return;
}
if (!request) {
  console.log('Web payments are not supported in this browser.');
  return;
}
```

Error Message:

Payment Request Error: PaymentRequest is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are testing it in an older browser that simply doesn't support it. Browser support is pretty good these days, [but not universal](https://caniuse.com/?search=paymentrequest). You just need to do a simple bit of feature detection and wrap your code in an if statement to check the browser supports it:

```
if (window.PaymentRequest) {
    // your payment request code here
}
```